# WebSharper KendoUI. Failed to deserialize metadata for: IntelliFactory.WebSharper.KendoUI

Tags: f#, kendo-ui, websharper

I try to use WebSharper and KendoUI extension with MS VS 2013.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938

Installed Version: Ultimate
```

WebSharper.KendoUI from NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSharper.KendoUI/

When I try to build my project I get the next error. Note that I this error occurs even if I do not use this package in my code but only install it.

```
"D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\build\/../tools/net45\WebSharper.exe" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Core.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Formlet.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Html.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.JavaScript.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Reactive.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Collections.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Control.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Dom.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Ecma.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Formlet.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html5.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.JQuery.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.JQueryUi.2.5.5.184\lib\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.JQueryUI.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.KendoUI.2.4.44.47\lib\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.KendoUI.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Testing.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Xml.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll"  "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\AlgoVisPage\obj\Debug\Raw\AlgoVisPage.dll" "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\AlgoVisPage\obj\Debug\AlgoVisPage.dll"
        [Error] C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA807.tmp(1,1): System.Exception: Failed to deserialize metadata for: IntelliFactory.WebSharper.KendoUI, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dcd983dec8f76a71
    D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\build\WebSharper.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: The command ""D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\build\/../tools/net45\WebSharper.exe" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Core.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Formlet.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Html.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.JavaScript.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Reactive.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Collections.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Control.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Core.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Dom.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Ecma.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Formlet.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Html5.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.JQuery.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.JQueryUi.2.5.5.184\lib\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.JQueryUI.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.KendoUI.2.4.44.47\lib\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.KendoUI.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Testing.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.dll" -r "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\packages\WebSharper.2.5.92.21\tools\net45\IntelliFactory.Xml.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll" -r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll"  "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\AlgoVisPage\obj\Debug\Raw\AlgoVisPage.dll" "D:\projects\ycGit\YC.edu\src\YC.edu\AlgoVisPage\obj\Debug\AlgoVisPage.dll"" exited with code 1.
```

Please, could anybody explain hou to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is due to the fact that your Kendo UI extension and your WebSharper are of different versions (2.4.X vs. 2.5.X, respectively).  WebSharper extensions are versioned together with their matching WebSharper as they use a particular "metadata" format to describe F# to JavaScript translation artifacts, so you will either need WebSharper 2.4 (which you can get from Nuget) or a 2.5-compatible Kendo UI extension to make the two work together.

Starting with 2.5, Kendo UI is a premium extension, so you need to be a licensed developer to use it. See http://websharper.com/store for more details.

Comment: Might also mention https://github.com/davidgrenier/Kendo - a user-maintained ext. by David Grenier.